# Strawberry Perl MSI installation error - 1603

Tags: perl, windows-installer, strawberry-perl

I tried to install Strawberry perl version 5.32.1.1 using the MSI installer for our 2016 windows 64 bit server.

```
msiexec.exe /i "C:\StrawberryPerl\strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit.msi" /L*V C:\StrawberryPerl\Strawberry-Perl.log"
```

The installer opened the setup wizard, but the installation failed with below error.

```
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:718]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Strawberry Perl (64-bit). Product Version: 5.32.1001. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: strawberryperl.com project. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Found that the MSI 1603 error could be due to,

```
Cause
You may receive this error message if any one of the following conditions is true:

Windows Installer is attempting to install an app that is already installed on your PC.

The folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is encrypted.

The drive that contains the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is accessed as a substitute drive.

The SYSTEM account does not have Full Control permissions on the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to. You notice the error message because the Windows Installer service uses the SYSTEM account to install software.
```

In my case, I have installed the **Active Perl** already on the server. Please advise if this is the root cause of the installation issue.

```
Value 3 from Log:

MSI (c) (78:00) [18:28:33:113]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:28:33:113]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 18:28:33: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:28:33:113]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 18:28:33: FatalError. 
Action start 18:28:33: FatalError.
Action 18:28:33: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 18:29:51: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 18:29:51: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:51:312]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (78:E4) [18:29:51:328]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {DBA41113-4E91-3FFC-B400-573BB4B80705}
Property(C): WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1
```

Additional Log:

```
Property(C): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID = 1
=== Logging stopped: 1/28/2022  18:29:52 ===
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:718]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:718]: Product: Strawberry Perl (64-bit) -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:718]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Strawberry Perl (64-bit). Product Version: 5.32.1001. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: strawberryperl.com project. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:734]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:734]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (78:00) [18:29:52:750]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 1/28/2022  18:29:53 ===
```

Regards...

Comment: Hakon, that was a typo ..I have corrected it now

Comment: Is that filtered? It seems filtered beyond usefulness

Comment: @ikegami, are you referring to the Value 3 Log or the msiexec command?

Comment: The log file lines you provided

Comment: as alternative: Strawberry Perl always publishes a portable version (zip). Uncompress it, add to PATH (warning: avoid potential collision with ActiveState)

Comment: thanks @ikegami I have attached additional log.

value 3 log is attached as per Rob Mensching comment below.

Comment: @MiguelPrz  as per 1603 error, Windows Installer is attempting to install an app that is already installed on your PC. In my current scenario, there is Activestate perl already running on the same machine. Do you think there is a conflict due to both software ?

Comment: @Learning_something_new: I really don't know. I have proposed another way to get Strawberry Perl installed in your system, if you finally cannot fix the MSI problem

Comment: What is this? You now have two logs, neither of which looks complete.

Comment: @MiguelPrz Thanks for the advise. I have the issue resolved by installing the other option.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1603 just tells you something went wrong during the installation. To discover the root of the issue, you'll want to dig into the log file. [I always start by searching the log for `value 3`](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/).

From there you should be able to find what really is preventing the installation.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Mensching for looking into it. I have added the Value 3 from the log. Unfortunately to my little brain I am not able to find any useful info.